# How to fix nullPointerException in newInstance of JAXB Context

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall my XML document into some java objects. While calling the newInstance methode of JAXBContext I am getting a NullPointerException. I am using JDK 1.8.

This is my error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:390)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)  at
>   de.bwb.TestOrgCompare.main(TestOrgCompare.java:58)

I have an jaxb.properties file in my object package with following content:
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory

I have imported 2 external jars: jaxb-api.jar and jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar and put them into a lib folder in my project.

I already tried to use org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory in my jaxb.properties file and imported org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar but i got the same NullPointerException.

Here is my code snippet:

```
            [...]
            javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            DTORGANISATIONSYST dtorganisationSyst = null;
            try {
                //the following line is line 58: where the error appears
                jaxbContext = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(DTORGANISATIONSYST.class);
                javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                //Overloaded methods to unmarshal from different xml sources
                dtorganisationSyst = (DTORGANISATIONSYST) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new StringReader(xmlString) );

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
           [...]
```

This is my DTORGANISATIONSYST Object:

```
    //
// Diese Datei wurde mit der JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 generiert 
// Siehe <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Änderungen an dieser Datei gehen bei einer Neukompilierung des Quellschemas verloren. 
// Generiert: 2019.07.19 um 12:43:25 PM CEST 
//


package de.bwb.bant.objects;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java-Klasse für DT_ORGANISATION_SYST complex type.
 * 
 * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="DT_ORGANISATION_SYST">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="HCM" type="{urn:bwb.de:ps:bant}DT_ORGANISATION_BASE" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="BA" type="{urn:bwb.de:ps:bant}DT_ORGANISATION_BASE" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DT_ORGANISATION_SYST", propOrder = {
    "hcm",
    "ba"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="MT_ORGANISATION_SYST")
public class DTORGANISATIONSYST {

    @XmlElement(name = "HCM")
    protected DTORGANISATIONBASE hcm;
    @XmlElement(name = "BA")
    protected DTORGANISATIONBASE ba;

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der hcm-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link DTORGANISATIONBASE }
     *     
     */
    public DTORGANISATIONBASE getHCM() {
        return hcm;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der hcm-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link DTORGANISATIONBASE }
     *     
     */
    public void setHCM(DTORGANISATIONBASE value) {
        this.hcm = value;
    }

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der ba-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link DTORGANISATIONBASE }
     *     
     */
    public DTORGANISATIONBASE getBA() {
        return ba;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der ba-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link DTORGANISATIONBASE }
     *     
     */
    public void setBA(DTORGANISATIONBASE value) {
        this.ba = value;
    }

}
```

And this is my DTORGANISATIONBASE Class:

```
    //
// Diese Datei wurde mit der JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 generiert 
// Siehe <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Änderungen an dieser Datei gehen bei einer Neukompilierung des Quellschemas verloren. 
// Generiert: 2019.07.21 um 10:27:45 AM CEST 
//


package de.bwb.bant.objects;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java-Klasse für DT_ORGANISATION_BASE complex type.
 * 
 * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="DT_ORGANISATION_BASE">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="SESSION_ID" type="{urn:bwb.de:ps:bant}DT_SESSION_ID_BASE" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="ITEM" maxOccurs="unbounded">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="ORG_HCM_ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="ORG_BA_ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="PAR_HCM_ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="PAR_BA_ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="DESCR" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="ACTIV" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DT_ORGANISATION_BASE", propOrder = {
    "sessionid",
    "item"
})
public class DTORGANISATIONBASE {

    @XmlElement(name = "SESSION_ID")
    protected String sessionid;
    @XmlElement(name = "ITEM", required = true)
    protected List<DTORGANISATIONBASE.ITEM> item;

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der sessionid-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getSESSIONID() {
        return sessionid;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der sessionid-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setSESSIONID(String value) {
        this.sessionid = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the item property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the item property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getITEM().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link DTORGANISATIONBASE.ITEM }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<DTORGANISATIONBASE.ITEM> getITEM() {
        if (item == null) {
            item = new ArrayList<DTORGANISATIONBASE.ITEM>();
        }
        return this.item;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java-Klasse für anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="ORG_HCM_ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
     *         &lt;element name="ORG_BA_ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer" minOccurs="0"/>
     *         &lt;element name="PAR_HCM_ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
     *         &lt;element name="PAR_BA_ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer" minOccurs="0"/>
     *         &lt;element name="DESCR" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
     *         &lt;element name="ACTIV" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "orghcmid",
        "orgbaid",
        "parhcmid",
        "parbaid",
        "descr",
        "activ"
    })
    public static class ITEM {

        @XmlElement(name = "ORG_HCM_ID")
        protected String orghcmid;
        @XmlElement(name = "ORG_BA_ID")
        protected BigInteger orgbaid;
        @XmlElement(name = "PAR_HCM_ID")
        protected String parhcmid;
        @XmlElement(name = "PAR_BA_ID")
        protected BigInteger parbaid;
        @XmlElement(name = "DESCR")
        protected String descr;
        @XmlElement(name = "ACTIV")
        protected String activ;

        /**
         * Ruft den Wert der orghcmid-Eigenschaft ab.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getORGHCMID() {
            return orghcmid;
        }

        /**
         * Legt den Wert der orghcmid-Eigenschaft fest.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setORGHCMID(String value) {
            this.orghcmid = value;
        }

        /**
         * Ruft den Wert der orgbaid-Eigenschaft ab.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link BigInteger }
         *     
         */
        public BigInteger getORGBAID() {
            return orgbaid;
        }

        /**
         * Legt den Wert der orgbaid-Eigenschaft fest.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link BigInteger }
         *     
         */
        public void setORGBAID(BigInteger value) {
            this.orgbaid = value;
        }

        /**
         * Ruft den Wert der parhcmid-Eigenschaft ab.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getPARHCMID() {
            return parhcmid;
        }

        /**
         * Legt den Wert der parhcmid-Eigenschaft fest.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setPARHCMID(String value) {
            this.parhcmid = value;
        }

        /**
         * Ruft den Wert der parbaid-Eigenschaft ab.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link BigInteger }
         *     
         */
        public BigInteger getPARBAID() {
            return parbaid;
        }

        /**
         * Legt den Wert der parbaid-Eigenschaft fest.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link BigInteger }
         *     
         */
        public void setPARBAID(BigInteger value) {
            this.parbaid = value;
        }

        /**
         * Ruft den Wert der descr-Eigenschaft ab.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getDESCR() {
            return descr;
        }

        /**
         * Legt den Wert der descr-Eigenschaft fest.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setDESCR(String value) {
            this.descr = value;
        }

        /**
         * Ruft den Wert der activ-Eigenschaft ab.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getACTIV() {
            return activ;
        }

        /**
         * Legt den Wert der activ-Eigenschaft fest.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setACTIV(String value) {
            this.activ = value;
        }

    }

}
```

I have not much experiance with Jaxb and marshalling/unmarshalling XML documents and hope you can give me some hints.

**One notice**: If I delete the jaxb.properties file, the code works properly. But I need to export my code (as jar archive) to another System and this system needs a jaxb.properties file to run my classes. So it has to work with this file.

Therefore after solving this NullPointerException the rest of the code should be allright.

Many thanks for you help!

Greetings Enrico

Comment: works for me ... even after using `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory` (eclipselink) instead, I am still unable to reproduce the NPE / might be something else in your project

Comment: I deleted the libraries and getting an Class not found error:
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory]
Did you create a jaxb.properties file?

Comment: Yes. `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory` is an interface, you need an implementation

Comment: Where shall i implement it and what is the content?

Comment: You misunderstood. Change the content of your `jaxb.properties` to `javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory` and add a dependency to eclipselink (for example, any other dependency that implements the JAXBContextFactory should work as well).

Comment: Man, you are great! Many thanks, it worked!!! Please Post your answer, I will mark it as solution :)

Comment: I added it as an answer, so your problem with the NPE was probably something else. Not sure what exactly ... / On another note: Judging from your comments the classes are generated, so I wonder why they do not conform to the java code conventions ;)

Comment: After setting up the dependencies to eclipselink and change the jaxb.properties to ..eclipse.persistence... it worked. I wonder why jaxb didn't. I used the Standard Eclipse generate Class from xsd Schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to reproduce the `NullPointerException`, but I noticed two things:

1. The `jaxb.properties` files has to contain a reference to an implementation of the `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory`, which is only an interface.

   For example the eclipselink implementation:

```
   javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

---

2. Also in Java 8 `JAXB` is still part of the standard environment, but its an slightly older version (2.2.8). However even in a new project I didn't have the NPE problem when adding an additional newer jaxb version in the maven dependencies.